# S/MIME for OWA in Chrome on Linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, activex, smime

Here's my problem.

I need to find a way of using S/MIME within Outlook Web App. The browser needs to be Chrome and the OS is Linux. I've searched all over with not much luck?

I found Tampermonkey for chrome which lets you inject your own userscripts but I need a way of tricking the activex control to think it's installed so S/MIME can run.